# Prevent delay while returning from C-Python api

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I have C-Python api like below.  It works fine, but the problem is while invoking this method 
from python script say

In `script.py`:

```
 offset=0
 size=4
 write_object(offset,size)
```

This calls `write_this_c()` C API and returns quickly to the next `printf` statement.
But the return call (`Py_RETURN_NONE`) takes something like 4-6 seconds.

```
static
PyMethodDef xyz_methods[] = {
{"write_object", write_object, METH_VARARGS,"write some stuff "},
{NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static PyObject* 
write_object(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)                                                   
{   
    int offset, size;                                                                
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"ii", &offset, &size))
            Py_RETURN_NONE;

    printf("before call"); 
    write_this_c(offset, size);                                              
    printf("after call"); 
    Py_RETURN_NONE;          ##delay happens here                                                                        
}
```

How to avoid this delay time?

Comment: How do you measure that delay? There is no such delay in the C-API *normally*; otherwise none of the Python built-ins would ever work without stalling Python.

Comment: When the script.py is executed, it prints out 'after call' and then takes few seconds to return.  Wait a second - seems like it core dumps that why it might have delayed "segmentation fault (core dumped)  python" ..Probably fixing core dump should fix the delay